# How do I get bulletphysics/bulletsharps' multithreading working?

Tags: c#, multithreading, bulletphysics

That is to say, what is the minimum set of code I need to set up the BulletSharp physics engine wrappers' "DynamicsWorld" to use "BulletSharp.MultiThreaded.ParallelConstraintSolver"? Alternately, I could probably work it out from the same set of code for the BulletPhysics engine itself.

If I have not phrased the right question, I would appreciate clarification; I only started using it today. (Yes, I have written a quick program using the standard classes).

BulletPhysics is a C++ library; the wrapper is written in C#.

http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/

http://code.google.com/p/bulletsharp/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally attempted to get multithreading working yet, but I'd recommend looking at page 42 in the [user manual](http://bulletphysics.com/ftp/pub/test/physics/Bullet_User_Manual.pdf), as it points out where to look for examples. They're in C++, but it should help get you started, at the very least.