# Multithreading in BulletPhysics / BulletSharp?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, bulletphysics

Could *BulletSharp* (or *BulletPhysics* itself, if you don't know about *BulletSharp*) work in multithreading mode?
If so, where could I find appropriate settings? (like on/off multithreading, numOfThreads, ...)

*note: BulletSharp is C# wrapper for BulletPhysics.*

PS: I know, there is [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096451/how-do-i-get-bulletphysics-bulletsharps-multithreading-working), but:
- there are no comprehensive answer
- much water has flown under the bridge since that time
- in present-day *BulletSharp* / *BulletPhysics* versions I could not find mentioned classes.

Thank you for any information

Comment: Wildly offtopic: "much water has flown under the bridge since that time"... that's a lovely expression. What language is it from?

Comment: @Thomas, =) My native language is Russian. And in this language there is similar one (but w/o a bridge). I fed google-translate with it and got this one (for the English). I hoped, it's from English. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multithreading in Bullet was recently revived. [BulletSharp](http://andrestraks.github.io/BulletSharp/) P/Invoke 0.10 added multithreading and the [demo](https://github.com/AndresTraks/BulletSharpPInvoke/blob/master/BulletSharp/demos/MultiThreadedDemo/MultiThreadedDemo.cs) shows how to set it up.

Use CollisionDispatcherMultiThreaded, ConstraintSolverPoolMultiThreaded, DiscreteDynamicsWorldMultiThreaded in place of the single threaded classes and set up some available scheduler (OpenMP, PPL or TBB) at Threads.TaskScheduler.

Multithreading will be added to BulletSharp C++/CLI soon if that is what you are using.

Work on the GPU pipeline in Bullet 3 seems to have stopped, so there are currently no plans to support version 3 in BulletSharp.