# CUDA in BulletPhysics / BulletSharp?

Tags: bulletphysics

Could *BulletSharp* (or *BulletPhysics* itself, if you don't know about *BulletSharp*) use CUDA? If so, where could I find appropriate settings? (like on/off CUDA, e.t.c.)

I found old info, that there was experiments with using CUDA in Bullet. But can't find info about actual state. (and didn't find any mention in *BulletSharp* or *BulletPhysics* code)

*note: BulletSharp is C# wrapper for BulletPhysics.*

Thank you for any information

Answer (score 0):

I think, @Andres Traks answered this question also in his answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080759/multithreading-in-bulletphysics-bulletsharp#comment79154731_46084935)
Namely:

> Work on the GPU pipeline in Bullet 3 seems to have stopped, so there are currently no plans to support version 3 in BulletSharp.